# How to install Kubernetes from release binary on Centos 7

Tags: kubernetes

I've downloaded kubernetes binary release 1.4.1 and want to install it on my Centos 7 cluster. The official guide is based on "yum install ...".

Is there any guide/instruction show me how to install and configure k8s using a binary release?

Highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same setup too. After hours of googling I decided to go the kubeadm way.

```
wget https://github.com/kubernetes/release/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd release-master/rpm && ./docker-build.sh
```

This produced three rpm packages of v1.4.3. After installing packages, simply run kubeadm init and that is all.

In addition, there is some nice [documentation](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/) for CoreOS , I tried to follow this first, but then I got compatibility issues in configuration between CentOS and CoreOS. Hope this helps.